# Where do arguments of \kern, \hskip etc. end?

Tags: tex-core

In TeX, code like `I\kern37ptlike\hskip100ptcake` works perfectly well. That makes me wonder how exactly the syntax of primitive commands like `\kern`, `\hskip` etc. work? **How does TeX determine where their arguments end?**

Does TeX just utilise the fact that (as far as I know) all length units consist of two alphabetic characters?

(I cannot see the need for a MWE.)

Comment: They keep scanning until they find `l` (ell) in the first case, which is not a length, then decides that the kern is ended, inserts the kern, and keeps going with the ell. The `\hskip` does the same, but with `c`. In case of an space, it's gobbled. Better use `\kern37pt like` and `\hskip100pt cake`. (Disclaimer: I'm a not specially proficient in TeX.)

Comment: I noticed that `\kern{37pt}` breaks. TeX is really the worst when it comes to consistent syntax.

Comment: The syntax is `\kern37pt`, the `{..}` is *not* the syntax. Of course it crashes.

Comment: I'm just saying I find the syntax inconsistent in TeX.

Comment: I think you're thinking of LaTeX, which would likely prefer `\kern{37pt}` if `\kern` weren't already a TeX dimension command, which has its own syntax.

Comment: I know that TeX was meant to support more different types of syntax, while LaTeX generally favours `\command{arg1}{arg2}`. However, what I find the most inconsistent here is that it would be extremely difficult for the user to make a macro with the same syntax. Thus this syntax appears only in the primitive commands.

Comment: @Gaussler Not *that* difficult, depending on what `\def\whatever{\afterassignment\dowhatever\dimen0=}`, then `\whatever37ptlike` would work and use `\dowhatever`, after storing `37pt` in `\dimen0`.

Comment: I stand corrected. `:-D`

Comment: @Manuel, but still, you use another primitive syntax (the assignment of dimensions).

Comment: @Gaussler I know, I mean it's not impossible, although you have to play a little bit (but not too much).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The argument for `\kern` is a ⟨dimen⟩, so TeX first looks for a ⟨decimal number⟩ (which can be an integer in any admissible representation, or a fractional number in decimal notation, with period or comma for separating the fractional part) and then for a ⟨unit of measure⟩, that is, a pair of letters representing one of the accepted units (pt, cm, mm, in, dd, pc, cc, bp, sp, em, ex). Any number of spaces between the numbers and the units are ignored, an optional space can follow the unit (it is looked for with expansion). Any other pair of letters will trigger an error message

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Thus `\kern37pclike` has a correct value for `\kern`, but `\kern 37 pc like` would have given exactly the same result.

Be careful with `\kern`, because it's a command that does different things if called in vertical or horizontal (or math) mode. Using `\enspace` before having started a paragraph will make you scratch your head.

The argument to `\hskip` should instead be a ⟨skip⟩; the same as before applies, but after the ⟨dimen⟩ stating the natural width, TeX looks for the keyword `plus` or `minus` (with expansion). If it finds it, it looks again for a ⟨dimen⟩ with the same rules as before, but the ⟨decimal number⟩ can also be followed by `fil`, `fill` or `filll` (not the real truth, but a good approximation) again with a trailing optional space that's looked for and ignored. Notwithstanding if `plus` is found or not, TeX looks for a `minus` keyword, same rules.

So `\hskip 2pt minuscule chances of errors` will trigger a puzzling error message.

The same as before is valid whenever TeX is looking for a ⟨dimen⟩ or a ⟨skip⟩. In case of doubts, particularly with a ⟨skip⟩, add `\relax`, which is what `\setlength`, `\hspace` and `\vspace` do in LaTeX.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the real truth (at least a small peak of it) with `fil(|l|ll)`?

Comment: An answer like only egreg can make them `:-D`. (Seriously, I could see it was his without looking at the name.)

Comment: @Manuel The keyword `fil` looks for a following `l` which looks for a following `l`. So `\hskip 0pt plus 1 fil L l minus 2 fiLL`  is a legal specification. And `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil Let's go` will make you scratch your head. `;-)`

Comment: Specifically such commands look for a 'digit string' which may have no digits at all, so that something like `\kern , pt` will give you a kern of 0.

Comment: @Jon Yes, there are sum subtle points in what TeX thinks is a decimal number. Indeed, a decimal number can also have an empty integral or fractional part (or even both); but if the integral part is specified with any other notation than decimal, it can't have a fractional part